How to compute this integral in dimensional regularisation?
I'm trying to compute the following position space integral as a function of $d$, which should be finite for $2<d<4$:
$$ I=\int \frac{d^d y \, d^d z}{ \left( |x-y| \,|y_\perp|\,|y-z|\,|z_\perp|\,|z-x|\right)^{\frac{d}{2}} } \,,$$
where $y_\perp= (0,y_2,y_3, \dots ) $, so that $|y_\perp|$ is the distance between the point $y$ and a straight line defined by setting the first coordinate to $0$, and similarly for $z_\perp$. 
It's easy to see that the integral depends only on the distance $|x_\perp|$. Also, by rescaling $y$ and $z$ it follows that
$$I = \frac{f(d)}{|x_\perp|^{\frac{d}{2}}}\,,$$
for some function $f(d)$, so to simplify the computation you can assume that $x=(0,x_\perp)$ with $|x_\perp|=1$. 
Still, I'm not able to solve this integral analytically, even in the case with $d=3$ instead of generic $d$.  
I've tried both with Schwinger and with Feynman parameters, but the integrals over the parameters become too complicated. Do you know if similar integrals have already been computed? Or do you know if there is some technique that might help to solve this problem?
